# Bootstrap 3 profile image in navbar

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get the profile image (see picture) to be say 25/30px without distorting the navbar?

This is what I have now:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/18x18" class="profile-image img-circle"> Username <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign-out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

this is the result:

[image: small image but no distortion]

But if I change the size of the image to 30x30 this is what happens, how do I prevent the distortion of the navbar:

[image: large image but a distorted navbar]

I tried clearing the margin and paddings on the image but that had no effect.

**Update:** Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJcrk/) of the current code.

Comment: I see that you use custom icons. You can check your css for that icon and make sure that it is correct for all sizes?

Comment: In this case it is not an icon, it is an image (currently a placeholder) but later on it will be the users profile image. So I don't see how your suggestion might help (sorry).

Comment: I looked in wrong place. But why don't you want to use CSS icons then? It will make sure you have right size of icon on all screen sizes.

Comment: @Megakuh I am using css icons (font awesome), but in this instance at this spot in the layout I want to show the users profile image/avatar, so I can't use CSS icons to display the actual profile image of a user as far as I know.

Comment: Can you explain how it distorts your navbar? Perhaps provide some visual guides how you want it to look exactly? That'd be great. I guess you want some extra padding between the image and the rest of the elements?

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJcrk/) of the problem. Yes I guess its a padding problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got it mostly right following what Kooki3 said, there's just more specificity in the Bootstrap stylesheet, so just change your `.profile-image` to `.navbar-nav>li>a.profile-image`

Editing your fiddle like this, the nav looks perfect to me:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a.profile-image {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: At a first look that worked, but now the hover is not correct anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/bJcrk/3/

Comment: Sorry, mistyped.  Should have been 10px top AND 10px bottom.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 16):

after looking at the JSFiddle, I found out the problem is caused by the height of the image you use instead of the padding.

give the image a class, and make it float left, then use position:relative to tweak the position.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle profile-image" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="img-circle special-img"> Test <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign-out</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
```

-

```
.special-img 
{
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    float: left;
    left: -5px;
}
```

My Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bJcrk/2/)**

Comment: I moved the profile-image class to the anchor, and set the padding to 0, but that did not have any effect :(

Comment: do you have any pages that i can use to check? can't imagine/reproduce the issue just by looking the image. thank you

Comment: I upvoted your answer but accepted @jme11's. Simple reason, that solutions to me seems more elegant. But still your solution worked :)

Answer (score -7):

```
//write you  script
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").mouseover(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").show();
    })
    $(".dropdown").mouseout(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ehm... there is no issue with the dropdown, the issue is with the image, the dropdown works just as it should.

Comment: what event? my friends